# MySQL - exclude all blocked users from the results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a little stuck with a MySQL query:

I have table **users**

```
user_id|language|name
1      |en      |Mike
2      |en      |John
3      |en      |Jesse
4      |de      |Wolfgang (Me)
```

and table **users_blocked**

```
user_id|blocked_user_id
1      |4
4      |1
1      |3
3      |1
4      |2
```

(where *user_id* has blocked *blocked_user_id*)

I want to find all users (excluding myself) who speaks English (en), I haven't blocked them, they haven't blocked me.
It should return only user with ID 3 from the example above.

I'm building a language partners search where it's excluding all blocked users (both ways) from the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, give this a go:

```
select * from users where user_id <> 4 and language = 'en'
    and user_id not in(select blocked_user_id from users_blocked where user_id = 4)
    and user_id not in(select user_id from users_blocked where blocked_user_id = 4)
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22a4/2

Comment: Yes on this data set.. it wont scale if you have many records.. check the "View Execution Plan"  those DEPENDENT SUBQUERY and FULL are bad news for scalablity

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.language, users.name
FROM users
WHERE users.language = 'EN'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM users_blocked
                 WHERE (users_blocked.user_id = 4
                        AND users_blocked.blocked = users.user_id)
                   OR (users_blocked.blocked = 4
                        AND users_blocked.user_id = users.user_id)
                 )
```