# Getting rows from two tables with a join and where clause

Tags: mysql, join

I am needing to get users from a 'users' table that are not equal to my username, but also not in a blocked table as the 'blockee'.

Using **only** the users table, I am doing:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username != <myself> AND interests LIKE <string>;
```

However, since I've added the additional 'blocked' table, I'm needing to further filter them.

```
mysql> describe users;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city      | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state     | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat       | decimal(8,6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lng       | decimal(9,6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| interests | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hash      | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| active    | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| avatar    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe blocked;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| blocker | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| blockee | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I attempted:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN blocked ON users.username = blocked.blocker WHERE username != 'myself' AND blocked.blockee IS NULL;
```

A pseudo-query would look like:

```
"give me every user that's not equal to my username, but is also not a blockee where I am the blocker"
```

So, if I had these values in the blocked table:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | blocker   | blockee  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | myself    | testuser |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

It would return everyone that is **not** testuser and had the same values in the interests column as the LIKE clause.

I hope this makes sense. I'm stuck.

Comment: Hi. Please see [ask], [mcve], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. This an obvious & easily found basic faq without MCVE & should be not answered but closed & downvoted. (Always google many clear concise precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your strings/names.)

Comment: Then close it. Btw, this isn't homework.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's homework.

Comment: I must not have understood the "hits googling stackexchange homework" bit then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - exclude all blocked users from the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345689/mysql-exclude-all-blocked-users-from-the-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the query that will do what you're looking for:

```
select *
from   users u
where  u.username != 'myself'
and    not exists (
    select 1
    from   blocked b
    where  b.blocker = 'myself'
    and    b.blockee = u.username
)
and    u.interests like '%what%';
```

I put together an example you can execute to see how it behaves: https://rextester.com/GPEC60793

Here's a copy of the entire demo:

```
drop table if exists demo_users;
drop table if exists demo_blocked;

create table demo_users (id int auto_increment, username varchar(255), interests text, primary key (id));
create table demo_blocked (id int auto_increment, blocker varchar(255), blockee varchar(255), primary key (id));

insert into demo_users (username, interests)
values ('myself', 'whatever'),
       ('testuser', 'blah'),
       ('somebody', 'foo'),
       ('nobody', 'whatfor');

insert into demo_blocked (blocker, blockee)
values ('myself', 'testuser');

select * from demo_users;
select * from demo_blocked;

select *
from   demo_users u
where  u.username != 'myself'
and    not exists (
    select 1
    from   demo_blocked b
    where  b.blocker = 'myself'
    and    b.blockee = u.username
)
and    u.interests like '%what%';

drop table demo_users;
drop table demo_blocked;
```

Comment: I ran it in my test DB and the results were SPOT ON. You seriously saved me a late night. I'd been trying for quite a while and came back when I gave up. Lol. Beautiful query man. Thanks for your help. Accepted answer.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce - glad I could help.  FWIW, @Nick's answer with the `LEFT JOIN` is also correct.  Not sure which approach performs better, but both should be equivalent in their result sets.

Comment: @Nick Thank you too! I was on my phone and this was the first notification I clicked on when I opened the SO app. I'll go upvote Nick as well.

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you the list of all users who are not you and are not blocked by you. You can then add other conditions (such as `AND interests LIKE <string>`) to the `WHERE` clause as necessary.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN blocked b
ON b.blockee != u.username AND b.blocker = 'myself'
WHERE u.username != 'myself' AND b.blockee IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=445132774a907626c426e25903af366c)

Comment: I'm glad @dossy mentioned your answer. This is great too. If I could accept two answers (since they're both right), I would. +1 though!

Comment: @IRGeekSauce btw I did create a demo while I was writing the answer, forgot to link it in though. I've added it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, you can try sub query.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username != 'myself' and user.username not in (select locker from blocked);`

I think it will work correctly for you

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. It returns everyone but me, including the testuser that is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work - but again I don't have your test data to test it against.

Cheers

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE ( 1 = 1 )
AND ( username ! = 'myself OR username not in ( select username from blocked ))
AND interests like '%string%';
```

in the predicate yo  may need to change the OR to an AND - as I said no data to test my logic.

HTH!

Comment: That returns an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of your blockee, then try to match those with your user table, if you cant find a match you will have null blockee, and those are the users you want.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT b.blockee 
            FROM blocked b
            WHERE b.blocker = 'myself') as b
       ON o.username = b.blockee 
WHERE b.blockee IS NULL
  AND u.interests LIKE <string>
  AND u.username != 'myself' -- if blocker cant be the same as blockee
                             -- you dont need this one
```